# Cannot login to jenkins version 1.466.2

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins and everything was fine untill i configured Security Realm in jenkins to Unix User/group database to a user named "build" as it exists on my build machine and now i cannot login to jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Find JENKINS_HOME/config.xml and put false for useSecurity flag. Please see below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.452</version>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>  <---
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
```

Restart Jenkins and try to configure everything carefully.